# jquery not working from cdn with django template

Tags: jquery, python, html, django, cdn

Here is my template section, loading jquery from CDN:

```
<head>
    {% load staticfiles %}


    <title>My Schedule</title>
    <link href="{{ STATIC_URL }}css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
        <div class="btn-group">
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" style="margin: 3px;">
                {{ user.username }}
                <span class="caret"></span>
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Action1</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    {% endif %}
```

yet I cannot seem to get the dropdown to work correctly, although it works fine in online simulators..

Thanks for any insight!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to place the `jquery` js file before all other js files. Something like this (Note the switch in order):

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: no errors, just success and '[02/Jul/2013 08:46:59] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 2310'

Comment: Just download jquery to same directory as bootstrap and reference it from there. If that does not work, the error is something else.

Comment: I was loading it previously from static files and that did not work, that is why I defaulted to the CDN reference, I am at a loss ):

Comment: Then you are solving the wrong issue.. can you try and create a fiddle ?

Comment: For some reason it worked loading from static and putting it before the bootstrap js! Thanks! I will look into the order of loading js files, evidently there is some naivety on my part of loading js! answer marked

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't the cdn be this one

```
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"</script>
```

Also, put it before all the js files

Answer (score 0):

To get mine to work, I put the reference to the static file directly below the doctype declaration.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

{% load static %}
```

I also removed the http part of the url when I listed it in the script src.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js" ></script>
```

Apparently, removing the http ensures that the reference works for both http and https